# Can a body be in both static and dynamic equilibrium simultaneously?

Tags: classical-mechanics, equilibrium, statics

I was just studying statics when I realized that a body can be in both static or dynamic equilibrium at the same time but I am not so sure.

My textbook says that an object at rest is in static equilibrium while an object moving with zero acceleration i.e constant velocity is in dynamic equilibrium

But.... Motion is relative so if two objects were moving with the same uniform velocity, they would be at rest relative to one another and therefore be at static equilibrium but since they are in motion relative to someone outside the system so they should be in dynamic equilibrium.

Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Isn't D'Alembert's principle already expressing dynamic equilibrium in the guise of a static one with all the accelerations, forces and constraints etc., ? See, e.g., https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/696928/dalembert-principle-and-euler-lagrange-virtual-displacement

Answer (score 0):

The sense of **dynamic equilbrium** which you mention - for an object moving at constant velocity - appears to be used only in the field of "statics", and isn't normally used in physics at large. In fact, the same term "dynamic equilibrium" is usually used in science for [something completely different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_equilibrium) - a situation where the object in question instead of not changing (as in regular equilibrium) does constantly change back and forth, or pieces of it change back and forth, so that overall, on average, it seems to remain the same. For example, some material may undergo some chemical reaction but also at the same time the reverse chemical reaction also occurs, which keeps the material unchanged in the big picture.

As you noted, in physics having a constant velocity is usually not different than having zero velocity - it some means you chose a different frame of reference, but the laws of physics (e.g., Newton's laws) remain the same.

But, as you also noticed, the distinction between "dynamic" and "static" as signifying non-zero vs zero velocity remain interesting in physics when we are discussing the **relative velocity between two objects** that move at different velocities. A good example is friction: You have *static friction*  between an object and a surface when the object is not moving against the surface (and it doesn't matter if both the object and surface themselves move relative to the Sun, or whatever), and you have *dynamic friction* between an object and a surface when the object and surface move at different velocities, so the object is moving relative to the surface.